# Exception in connection to remote DOMINO server through JAVA application

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

When I try to connect to the domino server from my java application i get an exception as follows:

```
NotesException: Could not open Notes session
at lotus.domino.cso.Session.initSession(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.cso.Session.<init>(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.cso.Session.createSession(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSessionUP(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSession(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSession(Unknown Source)
at com.nseit.email.ReadEmailRemotely.run(ReadEmailRem otely.java:23)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect Host: **127.0.0.1 Port: 63148** vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 1 completed: No
at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.ConnectionTable.get(Unknown Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.ConnectionTable.get(Unknown Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.Generic.getConnection(Unknow n Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.Generic.locate(Unknown Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.RepImpl.invokePreamble(Unkno wn Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.RepImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(Unkno wn Source)
at lotus.domino.corba._IObjectServerStub.createSessio n(Unknown Source)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.Connection.newSocket(Unknown Source)
... 16 more
```

***Here is my java code:***

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public static void main(String argv[])
{
ReadEmailRemotely t = new ReadEmailRemotely();
Thread nt = new Thread((Runnable)t);
nt.start();
}

public void run()
{
try
{
String host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:63148";
Session s = NotesFactory.createSession(host);

}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I am using **NCSO.jar** and I have verified all the setting of DIIOP connection is correct.

Since I am providing the **HARDCODE IP Address** why do my JAVA Application trying to connect localhost IP (127.0.0.1)

**Any suggestion on this would be of great help.**

On executing the following command  **tell diiop show config** on DOMINO server the console output shows several parameters out of which 2 parameters shows as

Host Address:  127.0.0.1
Public Host Name/Address:  127.0.0.1

Is this the cause for the above exception?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure why you are getting 127.0.0.1, but the error "Connection Refused" normally means DIIOP is not running on that port.

From the Domino server type

```
load diiop
```

After that try connecting directly to the IOR_TEXT to make sure it is running (using a web browser).

example:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:63148/diiop_ior.txt
```

You should get a string of numbers if the server is working correctly.